# How to increase java run time heap memory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I am using IntelliJ IDEA.
The java file will read a csv file line by line, the file is 3.8GB.
I think everything is in one line so that I am getting Out of Heap Memory error while I am using buffer reader to read line by line.

I have edited the idea.vmotions so that -XMx4096m, along with compiler's VM option, and the Run/Debug Comfiguration. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

However, the peak usage of my heap memory will not exceed 500mb.
[image]

And the Out of Memory Error remains.

Comment: Try running the application from the (OS) command prompt, putting the required `-Xmx...` etcetera options into the `java` command.

Comment: Do you really need the entire contents of the file in memory?  What are you doing with the data?

Comment: @VGR I need to parse the input file to construct my database, but everything in that file seems to be in a single line.

Comment: The error remains @StephenC

Comment: So that means that that problem is in your application.  It probably also means that the "peak memory usage" you were looking at was the IDE's not the application's.

Comment: @StephenC I am using the BufferReader to read the file line by line, the problem is everything is in one line. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Don't read it line by line then.  But seriously, if you want someone to help you, you need to describe your entire problem.  Or show us your code.

Comment: Have you modified the right .vmoptions file? There is idea.exe.vmoptions and idea64.exe.vmoptions - depending on are you on x86 or x64 installation.

Answer (score -2):

This could be a memory leak. I'd try using the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). It could be better than Intellij's built in one.

[This](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html) is a great guide I use when I encounter this problem.